# Angular service injection issue

Tags: angularjs

I'm new in angular and I have this issue, I have service and want to inject it to my controller.

I followed samples but I get injection error on my user service, this is my code:

```
var twApp = angular.module("test",['ngRoute']);
twApp.config(function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider.when('/',{
    templateUrl: "templates/home.html",
    controller: "HomeController"
    })
    .when('/setting',{
    templateUrl: "templates/setting.html",
    controller: "SettingController"
    })
    .otherwise({redirectTo:'/'});
});

twApp.service("User",["$scope",function($scope){
    var IsAuthenticated= function(){
    alert("This function is called");
    };
    return{
        IsAuthenticated:IsAuthenticated
    };
}]);


twApp.controller("HomeController",["$scope","User",function($scope,User){
    User.IsAuthenticated();
}]);
```

where is my problem?

And I get this error:

```
    Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $scopeProvider <- $scope <- User
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.14/$injector/unpr?p0=%24scopeProvider%20%3C-%20%24scope%20%3C-%20User
minErr/<@http://localhost/angular.js:63:12
createInjector/providerCache.$injector<@http://localhost/angular.js:3997:19
getService@http://localhost/angular.js:4144:39
createInjector/instanceCache.$injector<@http://localhost/angular.js:4002:28
getService@http://localhost/angular.js:4144:39
invoke@http://localhost/angular.js:4176:1
enforcedReturnValue@http://localhost/angular.js:4038:20
invoke@http://localhost/angular.js:4185:14
createInjector/instanceCache.$injector<@http://localhost/angular.js:4003:20
getService@http://localhost/angular.js:4144:39
invoke@http://localhost/angular.js:4176:1
instantiate@http://localhost/angular.js:4193:27
$ControllerProvider/this.$get</<@http://localhost/angular.js:8462:18
ngViewFillContentFactory/<.link@http://localhost/angular-route.js:975:26
invokeLinkFn@http://localhost/angular.js:8219:9
nodeLinkFn@http://localhost/angular.js:7729:1
compositeLinkFn@http://localhost/angular.js:7078:13
publicLinkFn@http://localhost/angular.js:6957:30
createBoundTranscludeFn/boundTranscludeFn@http://localhost/angular.js:7096:1
controllersBoundTransclude@http://localhost/angular.js:7756:18
update@http://localhost/angular-route.js:933:25
$RootScopeProvider/this.$get</Scope.prototype.$broadcast@http://localhost/angular.js:14720:15
commitRoute/<@http://localhost/angular-route.js:616:15
processQueue@http://localhost/angular.js:13189:27
scheduleProcessQueue/<@http://localhost/angular.js:13205:27
$RootScopeProvider/this.$get</Scope.prototype.$eval@http://localhost/angular.js:14401:16
$RootScopeProvider/this.$get</Scope.prototype.$digest@http://localhost/angular.js:14217:15
$RootScopeProvider/this.$get</Scope.prototype.$apply@http://localhost/angular.js:14506:13
done@http://localhost/angular.js:9659:36
completeRequest@http://localhost/angular.js:9849:7
requestLoaded@http://localhost/angular.js:9790:1

<div class="ng-scope" ng-view="">
```

And here is my body code:

```
<body> 
  <script type="text/javascript" src="angular.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="angular-route.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
  <!--<span ng-controller="GeneralController"></span>-->
  This it simple home page
  <a href="/#/">Home</a>
  <a href="/#/setting">Setting</a>
<div ng-view></div>
  </body>
```

Comment: which error do you get exactly?

Comment: Suggestion: use the unminified version of Angular locally and you'll get more meaningful error messages.

Comment: That was a very good suggestion, tnx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error says, $scope injection in the service has a problem. hence the service is not compiled.

try removing $scope injection into service and see if everything works.

note: $scope ideally should be with your controller and directives only.

Comment: Can't I use $scope in service? I'm watching a tutorial that is doing it and it works!!

Comment: But my problem was resolved anyway with removing it, tnx

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace `twApp.service(...)` with `twApp.factory(...)`.

Since you are returning an object, what you are creating is in fact a factory, so that may be your problem.

Otherwise, please include the error message.

Comment: Are you sure you have the same error using `factory`? Could you also either use the non minified angular.js or click on the link when you see the error and tell us what you see?

Comment: Yes, both was the same, but it was ok after I removed $scope injection

Comment: Oh yeah of course, you cannot inject a scope in a service: only directives and controllers have a scope.

Answer (score 0):

For me i've got these problem when i was using file://pathtohtmlpage.html, and the problem was fix when I hosted my pages on an apache server on Netbeans. Are you doing that ?

Are you also sure that you code is under ng-app='test' ?

regards

Comment: No, I'm using nginx and phpStorm. Yes, I'v set the ng-app, my problem was I was trying to inject $scope to a service.